# python, search file between two dates

Tags: python

i would like to make script in python , to search files recursive in Linux , between 2 dates?

```
import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):

    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

Comment: So whats wring with your code?

Comment: "Between two dates."  Is that creation time, modified time, part of the filename?

Comment: need to find the way to select files between 2 dates , for example 20150101 and 20150131, is creation time in linux

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
import os, datetime as dt

# define epoch time
t0 = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

# define time ranges
d1 = (dt.datetime(2015,1,1)  - t0).total_seconds()
d2 = (dt.datetime(2015,1,31) - t0).total_seconds()

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        f = '/'.join([dirpath,filename])
        ctime = os.stat(f)[-1]
        if ctime>=d1 and ctime <=d2: 
            print f
```

Comment: any sugestions on how to do it? , once the code above does not really work

Comment: Oh, my typing skills strike again!  f = '/'.join([dirpath,filename] must have a closing parenthesis (corrected above).

Comment: i just got no output , although i have the files , the program executes , but it don't give any output

Comment: did you change the date range?

Comment: I'm not sure how walk performs on Linux, but this works on my machine.  You should play around with walk while looking at http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/03/python-oswalk-example/

Comment: now it works, but i want to change create time to modified time? does mtime works ?

Comment: You should read the docs for os.stat, that will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: i had read on https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html , i change the ctime to mtime , but it did not work as expect, do i need to change something more?
but if i do 
print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('test'))
print "created : %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime('test'))

than it works, what should i do in code above to make it work , with mtime?

Comment: Are you sure you read the docs for os.stat?  You should not be using getmtime (though that will work).  You just need to update the "ctime" definition in the code I have above, which you could rename mtime if you want: mtime = os.stat(f)[-2]

Comment: my error was mtime = os.stat(f)[-1] , instead of mtime = os.stat(f)[-2] 
now it works, thanks.
if i would like to compress the files found by month , in the folders where files are found , how should i proceeed?

Comment: That is more than the comment section should allow.  You should open a new question for that.

Comment: can u just tell me for what i should search in order to implement it?
thanks anyway for u support

Comment: You could use the zip module.

Comment: Don't use `os.stat(f)[-1]`. Use `os.stat(fn).st_ctime` instead.